# btrfs mount options not working

Tags: mount, filesystem, btrfs

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

I converted my data drives with btrfs.
I first did `apt-get update` before installing btrfs-tools.

Unfortunately, that still only installed version 0.19

I can mount the drives, but the options compress=lzo and commit=60 are not recognized.
Since these options were not even present in v0.19, that's to be expected. I installed a .deb package, to update my btrfs-tools.

when I run `btrfs version`, the answer is `Btrfs v3.12`

So that's up to date now.

Problem is, I still can't boot with commit=60, and compression=lzo in fstab.

Fstab:

```
/dev/sdf1  /mnt/6   btrfs    rw,noatime,commit=60,compression=lzo     0  2
```

when I delete those 2 options, everything works great.

Could this be because the drives were converted from ext4 to btrfs, using the older version (0.19)?

If so, can I update the fs somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btrfs mount options are parsed by the btrfs kernel module.
You should upgrade your kernel, because Btrfs isn't well supported on older kernels.
Fortunately 12.04 has backports of critical 13.10 packages: [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends {linux-generic,xserver-xorg,libgl1-mesa-glx}-lts-saucy
```

This should upgrade the kernel from 3.2 to 3.11.

Btrfs in-place conversion produces a fragmented filesystem and doesn't let you select some important features. If you have the opportunity to rsync your data onto a new btrfs filesystem, use this:

```
mkfs.btrfs --nodesize 16k --leafsize 16k --features skinny-metadata /dev/YourDevice
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I have a few empty drives left, would it be best to use your method to make fresh btrfs filesystems on them, move my data, and then make fresh filesystems on the original drives?

Comment: @user upgrade first, move things later.

Comment: package not found... clicking on that link you Gabriel provided, gives me links for 12.10 and 13.04 packages. No link for 13.10 package available.

Comment: My bad, it's planned for this month. You could either wait a few weeks, figure out another way to get a 3.10+ kernel, or switch away from btrfs.

Comment: upgraded to raring. do I need to delete the old btrf filesystem before creating a new one? I presume it is necessary to move the data around?

Comment: I deleted the partitions on sdd and sde with gparted, commented them out in fstab, rebooted and ran your command 'mkfs.btrfs --nodesize 16k --leafsize 16k --features skinny-metadata /dev/YourDevice' . No errors were thrown, and when I reapply same command, it says that there is a btrfs filesystem. But gparted still says it's unallocated space.

Comment: Alternatively to backup+mkfs.btrfs+restore, one can run ''btrfstune -r -x'' on the converted btrfs filesystem. However this does not solve the fragmentation issue.